# jQuery XML Parsing not working with nested tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, cordova

I'm parsing an xml using jQuery (app in cordova/phonegap). To do so, I'm following [this tutorial](http://tech.pro/tutorial/877/xml-parsing-with-jquery).

It all works fine but when it comes to nested tags. I have this example XML:

```
.....
<preguntas numero="2">
    <pregunta tipo="TF" id="xxx" resta="false">
        <enunciado>El cielo es azul?</enunciado>
        <respuesta1>SI</respuesta1>
        <respuesta2>NO</respuesta2>
        <retro-pos>Eso esta bien</retro-pos>
        <retro-neg>No esta bien</retro-neg>
    </pregunta>
    <pregunta tipo="DE" id="zzz" resta="false">
        <enunciado>Desarrolla por favor:</enunciado>
        <respuesta1>PUEDE</respuesta1>
        <retro-pos>Gracias por participar</retro-pos>
        <retro-neg>Gracias por participar una vez mas</retro-neg>
    </pregunta>
</preguntas>
....
```

As you can see, I have 2 elements nested, and they can have different number of tags. When I try this in my js:

```
....
x=xmlhttp.response;
xmlDoc = $.parseXML( x );
$(xmlDoc).find("preguntas").each(function()
{
    alert($(this).text()); // This shows contents of all "pregunta" correctly
    alert($(this).find("enunciado").text()); // This shows ALL "enunciado" as one single string
}
....
```

How can I make it so it selects one "respuesta" at a time so I can get contents separately?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you meant this:

```
var x = '\n<preguntas numero="2">                                           '
+'\n    <pregunta tipo="TF" id="xxx" resta="false">                  '
+'\n        <enunciado>El cielo es azul?</enunciado>                 '
+'\n        <respuesta1>SI</respuesta1>                              '
+'\n        <respuesta2>NO</respuesta2>                              '
+'\n        <retro-pos>Eso esta bien</retro-pos>                     '
+'\n        <retro-neg>No esta bien</retro-neg>                      '
+'\n    </pregunta>                                                  '
+'\n    <pregunta tipo="DE" id="zzz" resta="false">                  '
+'\n        <enunciado>Desarrolla por favor:</enunciado>             '
+'\n        <respuesta1>PUEDE</respuesta1>                           '
+'\n        <retro-pos>Gracias por participar</retro-pos>            '
+'\n        <retro-neg>Gracias por participar una vez mas</retro-neg>'
+'\n    </pregunta>'
+'\n</preguntas>'
;

xmlDoc = $.parseXML( x );
$(xmlDoc).find("pregunta").each(function()
{
    console.log($(this).text()); // This shows contents of all "pregunta" correctly
    console.log($(this).find("enunciado").text()); // This shows ALL "enunciado" as one single string
})
```

Note `find("pregunta")` not `find("preguntas")`.

Also note that you need to have a single root element inside any XML document. so if there is other `preguntas` elements you need to surround them with a single element.

Comment: Just found at the same time that I had to search for "pregunta" not "preguntas"